# UWP Windows 10 app - Smooth Streaming support

Tags: c#, uwp, streaming, media, smooth-streaming

I am looking to port Silverlight app to UWP Windows 10 app. I read a lot of blogs saying it is possible to play Smooth Streaming videos in UWP, but as long as I can see - MediaElement and MediaPlayerElement support **adaptive streaming** but not Smooth Streaming (Microsoft implementation of adaptive streaming).

This article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-deliver-content-overview lists variations of adaptive streaming video formats.

(in practical terms) - Smooth Streaming video can be accessed by url like http://server/video.ism/manifest - and this throws exception when I use it in `AdaptiveMediaSource.CreateFromUriAsync` while other formats like Apple HLS (http://server/video.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl-v3)) works fine.

So my question - is there a simple way to play reliably **Microsoft Smooth Streaming** in UWP app? *[I have thousands of videos encoded in SS format and there will be no go for it unless we can play them]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a simple way to play reliably Microsoft Smooth Streaming in UWP app

According to [Adaptive streaming with PlayReady](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/adaptive-streaming-with-playready),

> Smooth streaming is also currently not supported natively; however, PlayReady is extensible and by using additional code or libraries, PlayReady-protected Smooth streaming can be supported, leveraging software or even hardware DRM (digital rights management).

It seems like smooth stream is currently not supported, if you want to play the smooth stream you may need the additional library [Microsoft Universal Smooth Streaming Client SDK](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Cenkd.MicrosoftUniversalSmoothStreamingClientSDK). And there is a [sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PlayReady-samples-for-124a3738) you can reference.

Additionally, we recommend you to upgrade your smooth stream videos to DASH.

Comment: thanks I am going to look at the samples. Could you please elaborate - how to "upgrade" ss video to dash ?

Comment: @BoppityBop,  I'm sorry I'm not familiar with video making  itself, but may be you can try to find ways on  [this forum](http://dashif.org). Thanks for understanding.